# Is a yarnpkg an alias of yarn, the node.js package manager?

Tags: yarnpkg

I know there are two yarns:

1. [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), the node.js package manager
2. Apache Hadoop's [Yarn](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)

I noticed that both commands work fine:

```sh
yarn --version
yarnpkg --version
```

Is `yarnpkg` a CLI alias that yarn, the node.js package manager, implemented to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if they point to the same binary by typing `which yarn` and `which yarnpkg`.

If they point to the same binary file then it's just an alias or a symlink, but if not, then they are not the same, although it is most likely that they both do the same job, and it is just that apache named it differently.

([Debian's yarn](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/yarnpkg/filelist) also uses `yarnpkg`)